# Stream mapping multiple types

Tags: java, guava

How can I convert this code to the one that uses streams? one line, if possible:

```java
List<Key<String, ?>> keys = Lists.newArrayList();
for (Map.Entry<String, House> entry : Houses.all().entrySet()) {
    keys.add(new Key<>(entry.getKey(), 
    HousesTypes.getFor(entry.getValue()));
}
return ImmutableList.of(houseConstructor.newInstance(5, keys));
```

Comment: "*How i can convert this code using streams if possible one line?*" - Counter-question: Why do you want to have a one-liner?

Comment: @Turing85 cleaner & looks better.

Comment: "cleaner" and "looks better" are both opinion-based metrics.

Comment: @Steven "Cleaner" can be objectively cleaner, and "looks better" can also be objectively looking better, but the phrase "one-line" is something I'm not sure about. I'm not sure you're going to fit this on your screen, as *one line*, per se; however, if you mean a one, non-interruptedly chained expression, that's something you can do. To me, personally, such complex snippets are virtually impossible to be "one-line" codes, whatever you mean in it.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri “make a function and call it” ahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, IMO "in one line" is not a great point to use `Stream` because they came at a cost, but you can do something like this:

```
return ImmutableList.of(
  houseConstructor.newInstance(
    5, 
    Houses.all()
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .map(entry -> new Key<>(entry.getKey(), HousesTypes.getFor(entry.getValue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
  )
);
```